# How to Authorised all projects in GCP with single GCP SA for terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automation, terraform, google-cloud-iam

want to create infra in GCP using terraform whenever any new project create in ORG. I want to create only one Service Account and using that SA want to create infra for any future projects as well, I want to automate it using bitbucket pipeline.

Tried to resolve this by giving the org admin access to SA but its not working.

Is there any way for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The *Organization Administrator* can do a lot of things but related to the [administering the organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization) and not necessarily to manage resources like projects, VMs, etc.

For example, if you want the SA to be able to create projects you need the [*Project Creator*](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#resource-manager-roles) role. Of course you want to add the necessary roles depending on what resources you want to manage.

In addition, I don't recommend to use the "All Mighty" *Owner* to manage your resources; instead use just the necessary ones (Read [Least privilege](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/using-iam-securely#least_privilege))

I'd suggest to first read the documentation and understand the purpose of every [GCP role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles).

Answer (score 0):

> How to Authorised all projects in GCP with single GCP SA for terraform

That is not possible. Each time a new project is created IAM bindings must be added to the project for the service account. Service accounts do not inherit rights.